# How do you do stratified sampling across different groups, when creating train and test sets, in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sampling, apache-spark-ml

I am looking for a solution to split my data to Test and Train sets but I want to have all the levels of my categorical variable in both test and train. 
My variable has 200 levels and the data is 18 million records. I tried `sampleBy` function with fractions (0.8) and could get the training set but had difficulties getting the test set since there is no index in Spark and even with creating a key, using left join or subtract is very slow to get the test set!

I want to do a `groupBy` based on my categorical variable and randomly sample each category and if there is only one observation for that category, put that in the train set.

Is there a default function or library to help with this operation?

Answer (score 1):

A pretty hard problem.

I don't know of an in-built function which will help you get this. Using `sampleBy` and then so subtraction subtraction would work but as you said - would be pretty slow.

Alternatively, wonder if you can try this*:

1. Use window functions, add row num and remove everything with rownum=1 into a separate dataframe which you will add into your training in the end.
2. On the remaining data, using `randomSplit` (a dataframe function) to divide into `training` and `test`
3. Add the separated data from Step 1 to training.

This should work faster.

*(I haven't tried it before! Would be great if you can share what worked in the end!)

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I did! just for the first step, I did a frequency and put aside all the levels with one observation. randomSplit is pretty fast but I am not sure what are the percentages of each level in train and test. I have to check and I hope they are at least close to 0.7 , 0.3!

Comment: I guess that's where the trust in randomness comes in! If its very important to maintain the distribution - maybe worth it to invest time to do a one time groupBy-and-sample for each category and then persist it.